# Visio Pro 2013 tree with more than 5 branches

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Need branch connector with 8-14 branches for plumbing diagrams, stock branch only 5 and it does not cooperate to connect two branches, TIA

Answer (score 0):

Put one or more on top of the first one.

You can edit the shape yourself. Open the shape's shapesheet, look at the **Controls** section, add a new row and duplicate the contents of the line above.
Now go down to the **Geometry** sections, add a new Geometry section, duplicate the section above but reference the new **Controls** row you created. Repeat for each new branch.